# Does IE9 have issues with the new textInput binding in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

According to the documentation, *`textInput` provides instant updates from the DOM*, meaning when a user is typing, the values update in real time.

In IE9 I'm not seeing the value update in real time. I do see it update on blur, but even then it's slow. Also, strangely, the update is instant when using backspace.

Is this a bug?

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/m2yfkyrk/

```
Hello <span data-bind="text: name"></span><br>
I said, HELLO <span data-bind="text: upper"></span>!<br>

<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: name">

function VM() {
    this.name = ko.observable("Homer");
    this.upper = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.name().toUpperCase();
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Comment: It's just you, seemed to be working for me.

Comment: Best I can check is the emulation in IE11, but its working fine for me.

Comment: *matter of choice* i prefer to avoid textInput rather i use  `value` binding with `valueUpdate` i.e keyup or keydown etc . cheers .

Comment: @supercool `textInput` was made for a reason. There are a lot of cross-browser issues, especially on mobile, with using those events

Comment: @Tyrsius i agree & good to know about those issues about events .

Comment: Obviously I'm a little late to the party, but I'm seeing the problem described in the question when testing the fiddle in IE9. I'll explore and see if I can find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that IE9 has problems when updating the DOM while processing the `propertychange` event that the `textInput` binding uses. A workaround is to add a delay to the observable using `rateLimit`:

```
this.name = ko.observable("Homer").extend({rateLimit:0});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2yfkyrk/1/

There is a similar issue open for Knockout: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1788

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an issue with your system. In addition to the commenters who noted that this isn't an issue, IE9 and this specific binding is part of the release testing done for Knockout.

It will be difficult to troubleshoot beyond this point. Try turning off browser extensions or updating.